# Google Earth plug-in for geckofx

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-earth, gecko

I use geckofx-10 (with xulrunner 10.0.2) in .Net4 winform.
I load Google Maps:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl
```

This work only for Street & Satellite maps and Google Earth doesn’t exist.
How add GE plug-in and active it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you have the Google Earth Plugin installed then you would just need to create your own implementation of Google Maps and then load that into your browser control.

You can use this utility library to do that with version 3 of the maps api
http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/

There is a working example of Map/Earth integration here:
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/googleearth/examples/earth.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is too late answer, but it may be useful for another users...

I tried another version of GeckoFX 1.9.1.0 (with XulRunner 3.6.26.) in .Net 4 Framework and it didn't work for me like you. So i decided to use static Google Maps and it worked like a charm.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?csw=1